# Put text containing lots of quotes inside a String

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a very long text when I try to put it in a String variable inside a quote mark or a double quote mark an error occurs because the text contains a lot of single and double quotes and some of them are not closed, is there a solution other than deleting the quotes from the text?

I use flutter.

and this is the text:

```
Once upon a time, in a small village nestled in the rolling hills of the countryside, there lived a young boy named Jack. Jack was a curious and adventurous boy who loved to explore the fields and forests around his village.
One day, as he was walking through the woods, he came upon a beautiful clearing filled with wildflowers. In the center of the clearing stood a large, old oak tree. As Jack walked closer to the tree, he noticed a small door set into the trunk.
Intrigued, Jack pushed open the door and peered inside. To his surprise, he saw a tiny, cozy room filled with all sorts of treasures: shiny jewels, golden coins, and sparkling crystals. Jack couldn't believe his eyes!
As he reached out to touch the glittering jewels, a soft voice spoke from behind him. "Who are you, and what are you doing in my tree?"
Startled, Jack turned around to see a tiny fairy with shimmering wings and a bright smile. "I'm sorry," said Jack, bowing his head. "I didn't mean to intrude. I was just exploring and I saw the door and couldn't resist coming in."
The fairy chuckled and flew closer to Jack. "There's no need to apologize, dear boy," she said. "I'm glad you found my tree. It's not often that humans stumble upon my home. My name is Luna, and I'm the guardian of this forest."
Jack's eyes widened in amazement. "A guardian fairy! I've never met one before. Can you grant me wishes, like in the stories?"
Luna laughed and shook her head. "I'm afraid not, dear Jack. But I can give you a gift, if you'd like. Choose something from my treasure trove to take with you on your adventures."
Jack thought for a moment, then reached for a small, shimmering crystal. "This one, please," he said, holding it up for Luna to see.
"Ah, a wise choice," said Luna, smiling. "That crystal will bring you good luck and protect you on your travels."
With a grateful heart, Jack thanked Luna and promised to take good care of the crystal. And as he left the tree and made his way back through the woods, he felt a sense of magic and wonder surrounding him, knowing that he had made a new friend in the magical guardian of the forest.
```

Comment: Try using the multi line string syntax https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#strings. Use 3 single or double quotes at either end.

Comment: Thank , its work ,I didn't know I could use three quotes